# jQuery - Click Events Bogging Down / Getting Hung Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I'm just making an index of guitar chords that lets you see all the notes when you click on one. You can see it here (so far only the A chords are finished): http://codepen.io/JTBennett/full/rWEOod/

The issue is that when you click on particular chords or multiple chords in quick succession, the thing gets stuck - sometimes it catches up quickly, others it just sits doing nothing. I thought it might be the images used (they're about 7kb ea.) so I stuck them in a pre-loader - no difference.

I'd appreciate it if someone could take a quick look and let me know if there's something obvious that I'm missing - here's the code:

```
function preloadImages(array) {
if (!preloadImages.list) {
    preloadImages.list = [];
}

    var list = preloadImages.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var index = list.indexOf(this);
            if (index !== -1) {
                list.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        list.push(img);
        img.src = array[i];
    }
}

preloadImages(["http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-4.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-dim.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-m.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-m7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Asharp-maj7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-plus.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-D.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-Fsharp.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-Gsharp.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A11.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A13-5.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A4.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A6.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A7-9-plus.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A7-plus.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A7-sus4.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A9.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab-plus.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab11.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab4.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Ab-dim.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Abm.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Abm7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Abmaj-J7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-dim.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am7-sharp.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am7-sus4.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am-add9.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am-G.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am6.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/Am9.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-maj7.png", "http://www.joeltbennett.com/guitar_chords/img/chords/A/A-sus.png"]);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".note").hide();
    $(".note-menu").hide();

  $(".btn-class").click(function(){
    $(".note-menu").fadeIn();
  });

    $(".note-men-closer").click(function(){
    $(".note-menu").fadeOut();
  });

  $(".chord-btn").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(slow);
  });


  $("#cb-A > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-1,#D-3,#G-3,#B-3,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp4 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-3,#G-3,#B-4,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp-dim > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-2,#G-3,#B-2,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp-m > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-1,#D-3,#G-3,#B-2,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp-m7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-1,#D-3,#G-1,#B-2,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Asharp-maj7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-1,#D-3,#G-2,#B-3,#E2-X").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-plus > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-3,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-D > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-0,#G-0,#B-2,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-Fsharp > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-2,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-Gsharp > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-4,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A11 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-4,#D-2,#G-4,#B-2,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A13 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-1,#G-2,#B-3,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A4 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-0,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-0,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A6 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-2,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-0,#B-2,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A79-plus > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-2,#A-0,#D-3,#G-0,#B-2,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A7-plus > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-3,#G-2,#B-2,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A7-sus4 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-0,#A-0,#D-2,#G-0,#B-3,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A9 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-1,#B-0,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-1,#A-3,#D-3,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab-plus > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-2,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab11 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-1,#A-3,#D-1,#G-3,#B-1,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab4 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-1,#B-2,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Ab-dim > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-0,#G-1,#B-0,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Abm > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-1,#A-3,#D-3,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Abm7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-1").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Abmaj7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Adim > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-1,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-0,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am7-sharp > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-3,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am7-sus4 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-0,#A-0,#D-0,#G-0,#B-3,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am7-add9 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-0,#A-2,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am-G > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-3,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am6 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-2").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-2,#B-1,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-Am9 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-1,#G-1,#B-1,#E2-3").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-maj7 > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-0,#D-2,#G-1,#B-2,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });
    $("#cb-A-sus > div").click(function(){
    $(".note").fadeOut(),
    $("#E-X,#A-X,#D-2,#G-2,#B-3,#E2-0").fadeIn();
  });


});
```

It's still being worked on, so don't worry if some things look incomplete.
Thank you!
-Joel

Comment: Have you gone through all of these click functions to make sure nothing is repeated twice? Wondering if there's an issue where a div comes in and goes out only to be repeated the opposite a few lines later.

Comment: I've just gone through everything on your suggestion and couldn't find any errors in that respect, still a mystery to me.

Comment: Give me a couple of illustrative examples that show this lag you're talking about. I think I know what you mean, but not entirely sure. Also, are there examples that don't lag?

Comment: Illustrative examples? I dunno what you're asking for exactly, but if you click the link to the codepen example, you can easily recreate it by clicking around the chord buttons in the A menu and watching the notes on the fretboard get stuck: http://codepen.io/JTBennett/full/rWEOod/

Comment: Also, I found a repeat note (Am7) and removed it, but it still didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I did play with the codepen, but most seem to be okay under the A menu. Some work better than others though it seems.

Comment: I did some more fiddling trying to narrow it down, and I believe that the issue has to do with the functions somehow stumbling on each other - but it doesn't seem like a timing issue...they don't get caught on themselves, changed the first fadeOut to hide just in case / you can click the same note over and over without issue.